# Efficiently blit texture rotated by 90° to renderer with SDL 2

Tags: sdl2

Let's say I have a 1024x768 `SDL_Window`, an `SDL_Renderer` bound to that window and a 768x1024 `SDL_Texture` into which I do my rendering. How can I render that texture such that it is rotated by 90° to fit the screen exactly (1:1 mapping between texels and pixels)?

I tried using the `SDL_RenderCopyEx()` function but I couldn't make it work properly with non-square window and texture, probably because it doesn't support scaling.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution (or *a* solution):

If W is the width of the window (e.g. 1024) and H is its height (e.g. 768), and if the texture has width H and height W, then

```
SDL_Rect dstrect;
dstrect.x = (W - H) / 2 - 1;
dstrect.y = (H - W) / 2;
dstrect.w = H;
dstrect.h = W;
SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, texture, nullptr, &dstrect, 90, nullptr, SDL_FLIP_NONE);
```

does the trick.

Comment: This works indeed and produced pixel-perfect result here (not tested all combinations even/odd). Thanks for sharing! User should just beware that W and H are width and height of *destination/new/rotated* texture, not source, that's why text counterintuitively says "(source) texture has *width H* and *height W*".

Comment: I am trying to use this method to display iOS screens for our rPlay desktop application, but failed to get it to work correctly. Basically it's 886 x 1920 texture, but needs to display as 1920 x 886 (90 degree rotation). If I still use 886 x 1920 window, rotation works very nicely, but of course it gets cut off. However, once I resize the window first to 1920 * 886, then rotation does not work correctly, only a small portion is displayed.

Comment: I figured it out, need to change width and height inside SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize() accordingly, then works perfectly for the rotation